# CSV delete all rows in the bottom 75% of lowest readings from column 3

Tags: csv, unix, applescript, sh, applescript-objc

I would like to delete all rows in a csv = 75% of the lowest readings from column 3 . Is this possible using some thing with “awk -F ',' '$3>= ….” Or would I have to sort the column with eg “sort -k 3,3” then count the rows divide the no of rows by 100 times 25 = x then use awk or sed to print only the first x number of rows in the csv. Thanks in advance. If system events can do the same as quickly,then AppleScript is fine

I’m analysing CSV files generated from the analysis of a short audio sample that contain estimated pitch readings, every 10ms throughout the sample, each frame’s frequency estimation has a probability reading from 0.0 to 1.0. I want to take the top 25% of readings with the highest probability so I can manipulate the remaining readings and set the most popular of the frequencies as a tag.

Comment: Will be helpful if you provide the part of input file and expected result.

Comment: @nowsnothetime – 
For simple CSV you'd need the option `-t,` with `sort`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].